# How to read private key from store

Tags: c#, rsa, x509certificate2

I have an x509 in my local computer store. How do I read in C# ? 
I need to use get the private key this way

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider).cert.PrivateKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the certificates from the "My" (personal) store.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certificate = store.Certificates.Single(c => c.Thumbprint == "Whatever-Your-Thumbprint-Is");    
store.Close();
```

At that point you will have an X509Certificate2 and you can access the PrivateKey property from it.

Comment: Yes I just need to know how to retrieve the certificate from the local store. Currently I have the certificate on the C drive and read it from there

Comment: @JohnM You need some way of identifying which certificate is the one you want. The certificate store can contain many certificates. Usually the thumbprint or X500 DN are used. The thumbprint is preferable since it is unlikely to produce duplicates. At that point, you can use `Find` on the `certificates` variable in the example above to find your exact certificate.

Comment: That comment of his was prior to my edit of the answer, BTW - might have read differently with the different context.. Yes, though, that's a good way if you are always looking for the exact same certificate from the store - the thumbprint.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that I'm looking for a specific certificate which I can retrieve either by thumbprint or subject. I'm using it with a web api application and is the best practice to save it to local certificate store not user store ? I just don't wanna keep the certificate in plain sight in a file directory so any advice as far as protecting it from prying eyes would be welcome.

Comment: Changed the above example to do a thumbprint check and retrieve a specific certificate.

Comment: Thanks this should work, haven't tried yet though. Now if the certificate has a password, so I need to supply it in the code somewhere ?

Comment: It should automatically prompt you through the standard APIs like when any application tries to read a cert.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void AddCertificate()
    {
        if (this.ClientCertificates == null)
        {
            this.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection();
        }
        X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(path, pass, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        this.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    }
```

Comment: That code will add it if the hosting class for the function is something that takes ClientCertificates, but I don't think that's what he was asking?

Comment: This how I retrieve the cert now and works but makes it easy to be seen by regular users. So I would like to put in local computer store and read it from there